# Manually send mail from terminal console?

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

We have a class that builds and sends a mail message.  I want to make some changes but before I do I want to test some things (like how URLs are displayed).  I'm trying to manually send a message from the console but I'm getting some errors.  Here is the `SendMessage` method of the class:

```
Method SendMessage(pSubject As %String, pMessage As %String, pEmailAddresses) As %Status
{
    set tSC=$$$OK
    set tMailMessage=##class(%Net.MailMessage).%New()
    do tMailMessage.To.Insert($PIECE(pEmailAddresses,",",1))
    for tI=2:1:$LENGTH(pEmailAddresses,",") {
        do tMailMessage.Cc.Insert($PIECE(pEmailAddresses,",",tI))
    }

    set tMailMessage.Subject=pSubject
    set tMailMessage.Charset="iso-8859-1"
    set tSC=tMailMessage.TextData.Write(pMessage)
    quit:'tSC
    Set tSC1=..Adapter.SendMail(tMailMessage)
    if 'tSC1 {
        //Log warning about being unable to send mail.
        do $SYSTEM.Status.DecomposeStatus(tSC1,.err)
        $$$LOGWARNING("Could not send email: "_err(err))
        kill err
    }

    quit tSC
}
```

From the terminal, I can instantiate the MailMessage class and set the body data but when I try to send I get an error:

```
USER>set tMailMessage=##class(%Net.MailMessage).%New()

USER>do tMailMessage.To.Insert("me@email.com")

USER>set tSC=tMailMessage.TextData.Write("This is a URL test http://www.google.com, thank you")

USER>set tMailMessage.Subject="This is a test"

USER>set tMailMessage.Charset="iso-8859-1"

USER>set tSC1=..Adapter.SendMail(tMailMessage)

SET tSC1=..Adapter.SendMail(tMailMessage)
^
<NO CURRENT OBJECT>
```

As you can see, when I try to `SendMail` it tells me `NO CURRENT OBJECT`

**update**
I noticed these lines at the top of the class:

```
Parameter ADAPTER = "EnsLib.EMail.OutboundAdapter";

Property Adapter As EnsLib.EMail.OutboundAdapter;
```

So I tried `USER>set tSC1=EnsLib.EMail.OutboundAdapter.SendMail(tMailMessage)` but that resulted in `<UNDEFINED> *EnsLib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you working on Ensemble Service. But for testing, you should not use that classes. For sending emails you could use [%Net.SMTP](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Net.SMTP) directly.
So, instead of ..Adapter.SendMail use this code

```
set s=##class(%Net.SMTP).%New()
set s.smtpserver="SMTP server name"

#; if SMTP server needs auth
set auth=##class(%Net.Authenticator).%New() ; use default authentication list
set auth.UserName="myUser"
set auth.Password="myPassword"
set s.authenticator=auth

set status=s.Send(tMailMessage)
if $$$ISERR(status) do $system.OBJ.DisplayError(status)
```

Comment: the `Net.SMTP` class required that I add a value to `tMailMessage.From`, other than that this worked as is.  Thanks!